# Cucumber failing to work after bundle update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

After running bundle update I have suddenly found that my cucumber tests are failing to get going.

Running cucumber features gives me:

```
$ cucumber features

Using the default profile...
uninitialized constant ActiveRecord (NameError)
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-expectations-2.3.0/lib/rspec/expectations/backward_compatibility.rb:6:in `const_missing'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/default_value_for-1.0.1/lib/rails.rb:23
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-rails-0.4.1/lib/cucumber/rails.rb:1
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/Users/petenixey/Rails_apps/kind-advice/features/support/env.rb:7
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:143:in `load'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:143:in `load_code_file'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:176:in `load_file'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:78:in `load_files!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:77:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:77:in `load_files!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:137:in `load_step_definitions'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:39:in `run!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:43:in `execute!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/../lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:20:in `execute'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.10.2/bin/cucumber:14
/usr/bin/cucumber:19:in `load'
/usr/bin/cucumber:19
```

I have tried "reinstalling" Cucumber using

```
rails generate cucumber:install
```

However this doesn't seem to have any effect.

My gemfile is:

```
source :rubygems
source "http://rubygems.org"

gem "rails", "~>3.0.3"
gem "sqlite3-ruby", :require => "sqlite3"
gem "hoptoad_notifier"
gem "pony"
gem "default_value_for"
gem "authlogic"
gem 'jquery-rails', '>= 0.2.6'
gem "rake"

group :development, :test do
  gem "faker"
  gem "launchy"
  gem "test-unit"
  gem "autotest"
  gem "autotest-growl"
  gem "autotest-rails-pure"
  gem "autotest-fsevent"
  gem "factory_girl_rails"
  gem "rspec-rails", "~> 2.3.0"
  gem "ruby-debug"
  gem "capybara", "0.3.9"
  gem "webrat"
  gem 'cucumber-rails'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'metric_fu'
end
```

And my gemfile.lock is:

```
GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    Saikuro (1.1.0)
    ZenTest (4.5.0)
    abstract (1.0.0)
    actionmailer (3.0.7)
      actionpack (= 3.0.7)
      mail (~> 2.2.15)
    actionpack (3.0.7)
      activemodel (= 3.0.7)
      activesupport (= 3.0.7)
      builder (~> 2.1.2)
      erubis (~> 2.6.6)
      i18n (~> 0.5.0)
      rack (~> 1.2.1)
      rack-mount (~> 0.6.14)
      rack-test (~> 0.5.7)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.23)
    activemodel (3.0.7)
      activesupport (= 3.0.7)
      builder (~> 2.1.2)
      i18n (~> 0.5.0)
    activerecord (3.0.7)
      activemodel (= 3.0.7)
      activesupport (= 3.0.7)
      arel (~> 2.0.2)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.23)
    activeresource (3.0.7)
      activemodel (= 3.0.7)
      activesupport (= 3.0.7)
    activesupport (3.0.7)
    arel (2.0.9)
    arrayfields (4.7.4)
    authlogic (2.1.6)
      activesupport
    autotest (4.4.6)
      ZenTest (>= 4.4.1)
    autotest-fsevent (0.2.5)
      sys-uname
    autotest-growl (0.2.9)
    autotest-rails-pure (4.1.2)
    builder (2.1.2)
    capybara (0.3.9)
      culerity (>= 0.2.4)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      selenium-webdriver (>= 0.0.3)
    childprocess (0.1.8)
      ffi (~> 1.0.6)
    chronic (0.3.0)
    churn (0.0.13)
      chronic (>= 0.2.3)
      hirb
      json_pure
      main
      ruby_parser (~> 2.0.4)
      sexp_processor (~> 3.0.3)
    colored (1.2)
    columnize (0.3.2)
    configuration (1.2.0)
    cucumber (0.10.2)
      builder (>= 2.1.2)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.1.2)
      gherkin (>= 2.3.5)
      json (>= 1.4.6)
      term-ansicolor (>= 1.0.5)
    cucumber-rails (0.4.1)
      cucumber (>= 0.10.1)
      nokogiri (>= 1.4.4)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.7)
    culerity (0.2.15)
    database_cleaner (0.6.6)
    default_value_for (1.0.1)
    diff-lcs (1.1.2)
    erubis (2.6.6)
      abstract (>= 1.0.0)
    factory_girl (1.3.3)
    factory_girl_rails (1.0.1)
      factory_girl (~> 1.3)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    faker (0.9.5)
      i18n (~> 0.4)
    fattr (2.2.0)
    ffi (1.0.7)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
    flay (1.4.2)
      ruby_parser (~> 2.0)
      sexp_processor (~> 3.0)
    flog (2.5.1)
      ruby_parser (~> 2.0)
      sexp_processor (~> 3.0)
    gherkin (2.3.6)
      json (>= 1.4.6)
    haml (3.0.25)
    hirb (0.4.3)
    hoptoad_notifier (2.4.9)
      activesupport
      builder
    i18n (0.5.0)
    jquery-rails (0.2.7)
      rails (~> 3.0)
      thor (~> 0.14.4)
    json (1.5.1)
    json_pure (1.5.1)
    launchy (0.4.0)
      configuration (>= 0.0.5)
      rake (>= 0.8.1)
    linecache (0.43)
    mail (2.2.17)
      activesupport (>= 2.3.6)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    main (4.4.0)
      arrayfields (>= 4.7.4)
      fattr (>= 2.1.0)
    metric_fu (2.1.1)
      Saikuro (>= 1.1.0)
      activesupport (>= 2.0.0)
      chronic (~> 0.3.0)
      churn (>= 0.0.7)
      flay (>= 1.2.1)
      flog (>= 2.3.0)
      rails_best_practices (>= 0.6.4)
      rcov (>= 0.8.3.3)
      reek (>= 1.2.6)
      roodi (>= 2.1.0)
      syntax
    mime-types (1.16)
    nokogiri (1.4.4)
    polyglot (0.3.1)
    pony (1.1)
      mail (> 2.0)
    rack (1.2.2)
    rack-mount (0.6.14)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    rack-test (0.5.7)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.0.7)
      actionmailer (= 3.0.7)
      actionpack (= 3.0.7)
      activerecord (= 3.0.7)
      activeresource (= 3.0.7)
      activesupport (= 3.0.7)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.0.7)
    rails_best_practices (0.7.5)
      activesupport
      colored (~> 1.2)
      erubis (~> 2.6.6)
      haml (~> 3.0.18)
      i18n
      ruby-progressbar (~> 0.0.9)
      ruby_parser (~> 2.0.4)
    railties (3.0.7)
      actionpack (= 3.0.7)
      activesupport (= 3.0.7)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (~> 0.14.4)
    rake (0.8.7)
    rcov (0.9.9)
    reek (1.2.8)
      ruby2ruby (~> 1.2)
      ruby_parser (~> 2.0)
      sexp_processor (~> 3.0)
    roodi (2.1.0)
      ruby_parser
    rspec (2.3.0)
      rspec-core (~> 2.3.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.3.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.3.0)
    rspec-core (2.3.1)
    rspec-expectations (2.3.0)
      diff-lcs (~> 1.1.2)
    rspec-mocks (2.3.0)
    rspec-rails (2.3.1)
      actionpack (~> 3.0)
      activesupport (~> 3.0)
      railties (~> 3.0)
      rspec (~> 2.3.0)
    ruby-debug (0.10.4)
      columnize (>= 0.1)
      ruby-debug-base (~> 0.10.4.0)
    ruby-debug-base (0.10.4)
      linecache (>= 0.3)
    ruby-progressbar (0.0.10)
    ruby2ruby (1.2.5)
      ruby_parser (~> 2.0)
      sexp_processor (~> 3.0)
    ruby_parser (2.0.6)
      sexp_processor (~> 3.0)
    rubyzip (0.9.4)
    selenium-webdriver (0.1.4)
      childprocess (>= 0.1.7)
      ffi (>= 1.0.7)
      json_pure
      rubyzip
    sexp_processor (3.0.5)
    sqlite3 (1.3.3)
    sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3)
      sqlite3 (>= 1.3.3)
    syntax (1.0.0)
    sys-uname (0.8.5)
    term-ansicolor (1.0.5)
    test-unit (2.3.0)
    thor (0.14.6)
    treetop (1.4.9)
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.26)
    webrat (0.7.3)
      nokogiri (>= 1.2.0)
      rack (>= 1.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.3)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  authlogic
  autotest
  autotest-fsevent
  autotest-growl
  autotest-rails-pure
  capybara (= 0.3.9)
  cucumber-rails
  database_cleaner
  default_value_for
  factory_girl_rails
  faker
  hoptoad_notifier
  jquery-rails (>= 0.2.6)
  launchy
  metric_fu
  pony
  rails (~> 3.0.3)
  rake
  rspec-rails (~> 2.3.0)
  ruby-debug
  sqlite3-ruby
  test-unit
  webrat
```

I've tried removing all of the code in my cucumber files to see if they're affecting things but it makes not difference. I'm at a loss as to how to fix this.

Comment: I've now tried running cucumber with a fresh rails app, updating ruby to 1.9.2, reinstalling all my gems and even with all of this I can't get this to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally discovered the issue here.

Since the problem appeared after a bundle update I eventually figured out that it probably wasn't my code causing the issue.

I tried doing a fresh rails install with the new set of gems and sure enough I got the same problem.

One by one I went through and tried removing gems to see if it made a difference. Finally I uninstalled the default_value_for 1.0.1 gem and everything started to run again.

For some reason there was a conflict between default_value_for 1.0.1 and something in the latest RSpec gem. I reported this as a bug on the default_value_for github repository so this may no longer be an issue but I have not tried reinstalling it yet.

Comment: Congrats. You might wanna use RVM (or Pik) to avoid gem version problems in future.