# How do I uninstall and reinstall *everything* to do with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber

I've had some real problems [getting cucumber to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5732778/cucumber-failing-to-work-after-bundle-update) and after having verified that the problems persist even with a clean instance of a Rails project and that they're at a system level I want to try removing everything in the system to do with Rails and starting again.

I've already tried removing all gems however that wasn't sufficient. What other things can I remove and reinstall to try and get the system working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to simply uninstall all Gems using `gem uninstall GEM_NAME`,
then use RVM to install a new Ruby version and make it the default one.

RMV also makes incredibly easy to remove a Ruby version and all its data since it installs everything in a folder within your home directory.

**If you want a clean slate, and then start over, do this:**

To uninstall all first remove rails gem

```
sudo gem uninstall rails
```

and then uninstall rubygems and ruby

```
sudo apt-get remove rubygems ruby irb ri rdoc ruby1.8-dev
```

Comment: I didn't actually have RVM at the start of everything so unfortunately it's not sufficient simply to remove that. I need to remove everything.

Comment: @Peter: I didn't ask you to remove RVM. You can install RVM now, and then add newer ruby versions, create new gemsets, set the new one to default and remove the previous ones as I told.

Comment: Hi Jatin, you may be right however I also wanted to get rid of all gems that were installed via "sudo gem install ..." before adding RVM. What I was concerned about was *anything* disrupting the system so I wanted to remove the gems that were also installed outside RVM. Your method may well have worked on its own but I wanted to be sure I'd flushed first

Comment: @Peter: Ok, for what you want, I'd propose that you don't go for RVM now. You want your system to be like new, before you installed any gems, ruby or anything related. Uninstall all the gems (even installed by sudo gem install)by `sudo gem uninstall GEM_NAME`. Rest, I have mentioned before.

Comment: I'd suggest using `apt-get remove --purge ...` rather than `remove`.

Answer (score 4):

One-liner to remove all gems:

```
gem list|awk '{ print $1 }'|xargs sudo gem uninstall -aIx
```

How this works:

- List the gems
- `awk` extracts just the name of the gem, ignoring the version numbers
- `xargs` passes that name to `sudo gem uninstall -aIx`; 'a' for all versions, 'I' ignores dependencies, and 'x' uninstalls binaries without confirmation.